# How to set function to button to uncheck radios inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I created table with a double loop.
For every cell i put 3 radios and a button that should uncheck the radios.
I can't do that because the functions inside the loop can't identify the correct radio (that has id based on 2 vars: 'NP'+medici[cas]+colonne[col]).
If I put the function outside the loop:

- if I put the function after the loop I get "function not declared" error
- if I put the function before the loop I get "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')"

This is the function

```
for(let cas=0; cas<6; cas++){
        
[...]
    for  (var col=1; col<6; col++){
[...]
var radioboxNM = document.createElement('input');
  radioboxNM.type = 'radio';
  radioboxNM.id = 'NM'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
  radioboxNM.value = 'NM'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
  radioboxNM.name = 'radio'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = 'NM';
  var description = document.createTextNode('NM');
  label.appendChild(description);
    const newline = document.createElement('br');
 tbodyTdAss.appendChild(radioboxNM);
 tbodyTdAss.appendChild(label);
 
  //crea radio NP
          var radioboxNP = document.createElement('input');
                radioboxNP.type = 'radio';
                radioboxNP.id = 'NP'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
                radioboxNP.value = 'NP'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
          radioboxNP.name = 'radio'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.htmlFor = 'NP';
                    var description = document.createTextNode('NP');
      label.appendChild(description);  
        tbodyTdAss.appendChild(radioboxNP);
      tbodyTdAss.appendChild(label);
            tbodyTdAss.appendChild(newline);
//Crea radio assente
          var radioboxAss = document.createElement('input');
                radioboxAss.type = 'radio';
                radioboxAss.id = 'Ass'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
                radioboxAss.value = 'Ass'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
          radioboxAss.name = 'radio'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.htmlFor = 'Ass';
                    var description = document.createTextNode('Ass');
      label.appendChild(description);  
        tbodyTdAss.appendChild(radioboxAss);
      tbodyTdAss.appendChild(label);
// crea bottone reset
buttonX[cas][col] = document.createElement('button');
buttonX[cas][col].innerText = 'Canc';
buttonX[cas][col].id = 'buttonX'+medici[cas]+colonne[col];
buttonX[cas][col].setAttribute("onClick", cancellaRadio(cas,col));
[...]
```

This is the function:

```
cancellaRadio = function (cas,col) {
    document.getElementById('NM'+medici[cas]+colonne[col]).checked = false;
  document.getElementById('NP'+medici[cas]+colonne[col]).checked = false;
  document.getElementById('Ass'+medici[cas]+colonne[col]).checked = false;
         };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `function cancellaRadio(cas,col) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `cas` and `col` with `let`, not `var`, so they'll have block scope. See [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

And you need to set the `click` event listener to a function, not call the function. You can't do this with `setAttribute`, it can only set string attributes. Use `addEventListener`.

```
buttonX[cas][col].addEventListener("click", () => cancellaRadio(cas,col));
```